# how to insert encrypted column data in SQL Server / SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have 2 (DB1,DB2) databases in SQL Azure.

```
DB1.Customer
DB2.Customer
```

Each has column called Surname which is column encrypted.

I want to insert records from DB1.Customer to DB2.Customer. I initially tried a Data Compare tool, but it omitted the encrypted column ie "Surname". Is my only way to do this, is to decrypt "Surname", recompare, insert data, re-encrypt "Surname" column for both DBs, or is there another way to avoid decryption.

I have also tried:

1) SSMS / Tasks/ Generate Scripts / Advanced / Data only but the encrypted data is shown as "binary" in the SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe parameterization is the key, excellent article here: https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2017/04/10/working-with-data-in-always-encrypted/

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @LeonYue, I did not. Problem is that parameterized queries are problematic when you have a lot. My next best idea was selecting from a copy table created via Select * INTO tmpTable where id =11. Using Insert with Select from tmpTable looked promising, however I need this tmpTable in another database and I cannot find a way to copy tables with columns still encrypted, to another DB. I tried Elastic queries but these seem not to support encrypted columns when creating the External Tables.

Comment: Can you try to using Data factory to copy the data from DB1.Customer to DB2.Customer?Here's the link [Copy data to or from Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this will not work: see: "Azure SQL Database Always Encrypted isn't supported by this connector now." in your link.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is refer to [Migrate Sensitive Data Protected by Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/migrate-sensitive-data-protected-by-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-2017).

The following table shows the recommended settings appropriate for several migration scenarios.

[image]

Hope this helps.